# Is it possible to specify only some of Type Arguments in a generic function?

Tags: dart

I am trying to extract a behavior of "check for an exception & return null if the exception was thrown" into a function, like this:

```dart
T? tryOrNull<TException, T>(T Function() innerFunction) {
  try {
    return innerFunction();
  } on TException {
    return null;
  }
}

// usage
DateTime? parseDate(String date) {
  return tryOrNull<FormatException, DateTime>(() => DateTime.parse(date));
}
```

### Q: is it possible to somehow define the `tryOrNull` so that I do not need to specify the second type argument (the `Datetime`)?

I would like for it to be usable like this, as there imo should be no need to specify the `Datetime` - the type can be inferred from the type of provided `innerFunction`.

```dart
// usage
DateTime? parseDate(String date) {
  return tryOrNull2<FormatException>(() => DateTime.parse(date));
}
```

Or to rephrase, How to specify the Exception's type better?

I am thinking something like Scala's `Try(innerFunction).toOption`, but with Dart's null-safety (which is imo so much more convenient than using `Options`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot partially apply type parameters. You need to wrap the function to do that:

```dart
T? tryOrNullOnFormatException<T>(T Function() computation) {
  return tryOrNull<FormatException, T>(computation);
}
```

If you do this often, you can abstract the wrapper:

```dart
T? Function<T>(T Function()) tryOrNull2<E>() => 
    <T>(T Function() computation) => tryOrNull<E, T>(computation);
```

which you can then use as:

```dart
DateTime? parseDate(String date) {
  return tryOrNull2<FormatException>()(() => DateTime.parse(date));
}
```

Alternatively, you can write both types at the call point, if you know them:

```dart
DateTime? parseDate(String date) {
  return tryOrNull<FormatException, DateTime>(() => DateTime.parse(date));
}
```

I can see why that's annoying, but for type parameters, you always need to provide either all or none.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot; splitting the type definition into two (so that one can be specified and the second inferred) by wrapping does the trick!